# How do I pass numbers to Java from karate? How do I call a Java constructor that takes a number?

Tags: java, testing, interop, karate

I'm just trying to figure out how Java interop works in karate and looked at examples like here:
https://www.swtestacademy.com/java-code-in-karate-api-tests/

My java class is this:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.lang.Process;
    public class Utils {
        double m_x;
    
        public Utils(double x) {
            m_x = x;
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    
        public static int exec(String command) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = run.exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", command});
            proc.waitFor();
            return proc.exitValue();
        }
    
        public double nonStatic() {
            return m_x;
        }
    
        public double nonStatic1(double i) {
            return i+1;
        }
    }
```

I can call the static methods, but not the constructor or nonStatic methods.
BTW, I know Java can handle function overloads, but I'm not sure about JavaScript, so that's why I use different function names.

One of my attempts to call the non-static functions is like this:

```
Scenario: nonStatic
* def nonStat =
"""
function() {
     var Utils = Java.type('Utils');
     var obj = new Utils(7.0);
     return obj.nonStatic();
}
"""
* def result = call nonStat
* print 'result', result

Scenario: nonStatic(int i)
* def nonStat1 =
"""
function(i) {
     var Utils = Java.type('Utils');
     var obj = new Utils(7.0)
     return obj.nonStatic1(i);
}
"""
* def result = call nonStat1 15
* print 'result1', result
```

I get:
javascript function call failed: :3 TypeError: Can not create new object with constructor Utils with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures.

I had hoped that a JavaScript number would be converted to a double?
The main function and exec function work. Both are static. I can get back a number, but fail at passing a number from karate/js to Java.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: BTW, I first tried with integers, but then I thought JavaScript only has a number, so I changed the type to double in the Java code. There are still some places in the Scenarios that refer to ints. It should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are some quirks in the JS engine. And we are moving to a new one for the future version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

I just wrote a few tests for the new engine: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/74ad0f2786730fd912f6bf2b15ebdf426e026206

So my suggestion is use `Number` as the argument type, that should work for all cases. And it would be good if you can test out the new version in development and provide feedback / heads-up on any issues you see.

Comment: Hi,

I was not aware that Java had a Number type. I come from C, C++ (and also Delphi, C#). Much of Java is pretty straightforward, except those differences :-)

I hope the upgrade won't break anything. I will check it out.
Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: The Number abstract class works like a charm. 
@Peter Thomas I don't know where you find the time to update the product with newer versions and on top of that support many users. And all that for free. Both product and support are greatly appreciated.